# How to Group consecutive records to fetch a record based on MAX and MIN of corresponding column?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database with different type of item types, consecutive HISTORY_ID, old and new values, field caption I'd like to filter and the date of change (can be not consecutive)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBGVS.png)

Tried to get the records using ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY

I'd like to get something like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBgKY.png)

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Including DDL, sample data and expected results in your question helps us help you. Images of data without data types makes it harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select [item id],[item type id]
    ,grouped_old_value=first_value([Old Value]) over (partion by [item id],[item type id] order by History_ID desc)
    ,grouped_new_value=first_value([New Value]) over (partion by [item id],[item type id] order by History_ID  asc)
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you question completely but I will give it a shot anyway.

I think you are trying to get the oldest and newest values of an item based on the time.

In that you want to find the value of old_value from your earliest record and the value of new_value from your latest record.

to select the oldest value you need to do group by item and item_type and get the first item when ordered by date (Or ID if those are incrementing over time) descending. .

to select the newest value you need to do group by item and item_type and get the first item when ordered by date (Or ID if those are incrementing over time). ascending.

that would result in:

```
select 
[item id]
,[item type id]
,oldest_value = first_value([Old Value]) over (partition by [item id],[item type id] order by [History_ID] desc)
,newest_value = first_value([New Value]) over (partition by [item id],[item type id] order by [History_ID] asc)
from table_name
```